# Continuous open image of locally compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, open-map, compactification

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. A subspace is called precompact if its closure is compact. Now, local compactness

**Definition 1 (Munkres):** Every point $x$ has an open neighbourhood $U_x$ contained in a compact set $C_x$.

**Definition 2 (given in my class):** Every point $x$ has a precompact open neighbourhood.

**Question:**
If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous and open. Suppose $X$ is locally compact, is $f(X)$ locally compact?

It is easy to show that the answer is yes, under **Definition 1**. Could someone provide a counterexample under **Definition 2**?

(**Note**: The two definitions are equivalent if we assume that the spaces are Hausdorff, so any counterexample must come from a non Hausdorff setting. That's my only lead.)

Comment: You can check for wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space